# Relative variable importance from CoxBoost

Tags: r, machine-learning, cox-regression, mlr

I am fitting time-to-event survival data using `surv.CoxBoost` in the `mlr` package. My question: is there any way to get relative importance for the variables in the fitted model? I have seen [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/14853/variable-importance-from-glmnet/211396#211396) post detailing variablke importance for cvglment but haven't seen any on CoxBoost.

Any idea?

below is an example of a model using CoxBoost`. You may need to install CoxBoost from [here](https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/CoxBoost/) as seems no longer on CRAN.

```
library(randomForestSRC)
library(mlr)
library(survival)
library(CoxBoost) 


data(pbc, package="randomForestSRC")
data <- na.omit(pbc)

set.seed(9512)
train <- sample(1:nrow(data), round(nrow(data)*0.7))
data.train <- data[train, ]
data.test <- data[-train, ]

task = makeSurvTask( data=data.train, target=c('days', 'status'))
learner= makeLearner("surv.CoxBoost")
trained.learner=train(learner,task)
CoxBoostfit <- trained.learner$learner.model

CoxBoostfit$coefficients
```

Comment: One simple heuristic that isn't necessarily robust but will give some measure, is just to sum over all non-zero coefficients for each variable. I tested this on your data (`apply(CoxBoostfit$coefficients, 2, function(.x) sum(.x != 0))`) and it gave surprisingly similar results to the `mboost::varimp` method on `makeLearner("surv.gamboost", baselearner = "btree")`

Comment: @RaphaelS I applied the sum for coefficient. Could you explain it a little bit more? It returned a vector of numbers. I want the labels for each variable and be able to rank them based on importance. I never used gamboost is that similar to CoxBoost?

Comment: @RaphaelS are the coefficient standardized coefficients? order slightly change with `makeLearner("surv.CoxBoost")`

Comment: Gamboost and CoxBoost use very different algorithms. What are you trying to achieve? In general CoxBoost has very good performance but the mboost package is easier to use (CoxBoost is archived on CRAN at the moment as well).

Comment: About the vector, say you save this to a variable `x` then you can add `names(x) <- colnames(pbc)[-c(1,2)]` to give importance. It's not a great approach, essentially it just says that the most important variables will be picked up by the model in earlier rounds. So if a variable is used in every boosting round it will be more important than one only used in the last round. I don't think CoxBoost has an internal variable selection method